# How to rename a table in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, rename, alter-table

The `SQL` query that I have used is :

```
ALTER TABLE oldtable RENAME TO newtable;
```

But, it gives me an error.

> Server: Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'TO'.

Answer (score 873, accepted):

To rename a table in SQL Server, use the [`sp_rename`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-rename-transact-sql) command:

```
exec sp_rename 'schema.old_table_name', 'new_table_name'
```

Comment: One more thing: if any of the table names has a `.` in them, use `[]` around the table name. (I know, I know, but dots can happen...) E.g. `sp_rename '[Stupid.name]', 'NewName'` or with schema `sp_rename '[dbo.Stupid.name]', 'NewName'`

Comment: And to add, _don't_ accidentally put the schema in the `'NewName'` field, otherwise your table might end up looking something like `dbo.dbo.NewName`.

Comment: Keep in mind that when renaming a table, you almost certainly want to **also rename any references to that table that may exist in stored procedures, views, functions, etc.** A quick google can find one of the many tools that can do this for you. Or you can use a script that finds a given string in all these objects, and paste them as ALTER statements, and do a find-and-replace, then run them all.

Comment: You can also create a synonym named after the old table name pointing to the new table `CREATE SYNONYM [schema].[synonymName] FOR [schema].[tableName]`

Comment: do not place new name in square brackets! otherwise the table will have square brackets IN the name. So: 'new_table_name' - is correct, '[new_table_name]' - will get you into trouble

Comment: @vacip if you say `sp_rename '[dbo.Stupid.name]'` the operation will fail. Correct: `sp_rename '[dbo].[Stupid.name]'`

Answer (score 163):

To rename a column:

```
sp_rename 'table_name.old_column_name', 'new_column_name' , 'COLUMN';
```

To rename a table:

```
sp_rename 'old_table_name','new_table_name';
```

Comment: Just a note here that `sp_rename` for Azure Synapse Analytics SQL Pools only supports renaming a column. No support yet for renaming tables or indexes.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-rename-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

Answer (score 29):

Table Name

```
sp_rename 'db_name.old_table_name', 'new_table_name'
```

Column

```
sp_rename 'db_name.old_table_name.name', 'userName', 'COLUMN'
```

Index

```
sp_rename 'db_name.old_table_name.id', 'product_ID', 'INDEX'
```

also available for statics and datatypes

Comment: For Column you're missing a comma between first and second parameters.
It should be: sp_rename 'db_name.old_table_name.name', 'userName', 'COLUMN'

Answer (score 16):

When using sp_rename which works like in above answers, check also which objects are affected after renaming, that reference that table, because you need to change those too

I took a code example for table dependencies at Pinal Dave's blog [here](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2012/12/02/sql-server-find-referenced-or-referencing-object-in-sql-server-using-sys-sql_expression_dependencies/)

```
USE AdventureWorks
GO
SELECT
referencing_schema_name = SCHEMA_NAME(o.SCHEMA_ID),
referencing_object_name = o.name,
referencing_object_type_desc = o.type_desc,
referenced_schema_name,
referenced_object_name = referenced_entity_name,
referenced_object_type_desc = o1.type_desc,
referenced_server_name, referenced_database_name
--,sed.* -- Uncomment for all the columns
FROM
sys.sql_expression_dependencies sed
INNER JOIN
sys.objects o ON sed.referencing_id = o.[object_id]
LEFT OUTER JOIN
sys.objects o1 ON sed.referenced_id = o1.[object_id]
WHERE
referenced_entity_name = 'Customer'
```

So, all these dependent objects needs to be updated also

Or use some add-in if you can, some of them have feature to rename object, and all depend,ent objects too

Answer (score 14):

If you try `exec sp_rename` and receieve a LockMatchID error then it might help to add a use [database] statement first:

I tried

```
 exec sp_rename '[database_name].[dbo].[table_name]', 'new_table_name';
 -- Invalid EXECUTE statement using object "Object", method "LockMatchID".
```

What I had to do to fix it was to rewrite it to:

```
use database_name
exec sp_rename '[dbo].[table_name]', 'new_table_name';
```

Answer (score 8):

To change a table name with a different schema:

Example: Change dbo.MyTable1 to wrk.MyTable2

```
EXEC SP_RENAME 'dbo.MyTable1', 'MyTable2'

ALTER SCHEMA wrk TRANSFER dbo.MyTable2
```

Answer (score 1):

Nothing worked from proposed here ..
So just pored the data into new table

```
SELECT * 
INTO [acecodetable].['PSCLineReason']
FROM [acecodetable].['15_PSCLineReason'];
```

maybe will be useful for someone..

In my case it didn't recognize the new schema also the dbo was the owner..

> UPDATE

```
EXECUTE sp_rename N'[acecodetable].[''TradeAgreementClaim'']', N'TradeAgreementClaim';
```

Worked for me. 
I found it from the script generated automatically when updating the PK for one of the tables.
This way it recognized the new schema as well..