# Mistake made while changing column name using sp_rename. (double colon created)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I made a mistake while changing the name of a column. I wanted to change a column name in my SQL database (Microsoft SQL Server). I succeeded, but I put a extra colon between my column name. That's why I can't change the name again now. The use of square brackets didn't solve the issue.

Instead of "table.column_name" does it says "table.table.column_name".

This also prevents me from executing 'select', 'drop' or 'update' statements. This is because the column is no longer found, giving me the error
`"No item by the name of '[table.new_scheme]' could be found in the current database 'name_database'"`

What I did:

```
exec sp_rename 'table.old_column', 'table.new_column'
```

What it supposed to be:

```
exec sp_rename 'table.old_column', 'new_column'
```

I read and used this article (in the wrong way :|).
[How to rename a table in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5335528/how-to-rename-a-table-in-sql-server)

Comment: Can you share with us what have you tried when you get this message : "No item by the name of '[table.new_scheme]' could be found in the current database 'name_database'" ? The code  please , not only select update or drop statements... Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

now you have to do this , so you put your column new which is "table.new_column" right now in double-quote or rectangular brackets like so :

```
exec sp_rename 'dbo.tablename."table.new_column"', 'new_column', 'COLUMN';
```

or

```
exec sp_rename 'dbo.tablename.[table.new_column]', 'new_column', 'COLUMN';
```

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you have a simple table:

```
create table mytable (id int, test int)
```

And you changed the name of the second column:

```
exec sp_rename 'mytable.test', 'mytable.test2'
```

Here is how you can rename it again:

```
exec sp_rename 'mytable."mytable.test2"', 'test2'
```

Here is a demo:

> [DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=7a3b888306573b9148954bff9deab015)

Answer (score 0):

You need to delimit identify the column inside the literal string:

```sql
CREATE TABLE dbo.YourTable (YourColumn int);
GO
EXEC sys.sp_rename N'dbo.YourTable.YourColumn',N'YourTable.NewColumn','COLUMN';
GO
SELECT *
FROM dbo.YourTable;
GO
EXEC sp_rename N'dbo.YourTable.[YourTable.NewColumn]', N'NewColumn', 'COLUMN' 
GO
SELECT *
FROM dbo.YourTable;
GO
DROP TABLE dbo.YourTable;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using SSMS object explorer. Snapshot is given below:

[image: Rename column in SSMS Object Explorer]